# Custom Control in VS Designer: Avoid serialization of Collection properties

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, serialization, windows-forms-designer

I made a new WinForms control

```vb
Public Class jwGraph
    Inherits Control
```

This control has `BindingLists(Of Foo)` in them. In order to avoid other Visual Studio errors in regards to serialization (error messages) I added the `Serializable` attribute to `Foo` and some other tags to the `BindingList(Of Foo)`.

Example:

**Foo declaration**

```vb
<Serializable> _
Public Class FreeMarker
```

**Bindinglist(Of Foo) declaration:**

```vb
<System.ComponentModel.Browsable(False)>
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
<System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
    Public WithEvents FreeMarkers As BindingList(Of FreeMarker)
```

When I use my control, Visual Studio adds base64 data ressources to the form's resx file and lines like

```vb
Me.JwGraph1.FreeMarkers = CType(resources.GetObject("JwGraph1.FreeMarkers"), System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of jwToolLib.jwGraph.FreeMarker))
```

to the designer. The problem with this is, that I can't change anything in the control's code after this point (or changing the assembly) in any way, because then the deserialization will fail and I have to go to great lengths to get it running again at all.

Many controls use collections. I can't seem to find the difference between their implementations (I tried looking at the basic controls in reflector) and mine, and yet their collections do not show up in the designer in any such way.

So how can I prevent the collections from being generated as binary ressources at design time?
They are initialized in the control's constructor.

My code is in VB.net but answers in C# are also very welcome.

Comment: your `FreeMarkers` property needs to be serializable/serialized: and `FreeMarker` may need some work too.  how does stuff get added to it at design time that it needs to be serialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like always, get gray hair for 3 hours straight, then decide to ask, promptly find a solution:

As described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx you can add `ShouldSerialize[...]` functions to the code to prevent the specific fields from being serialized. I guess the designer evaluates these functions and then decides what to do.

To keep with my example above:

In addition to

```vb
<System.ComponentModel.Browsable(False)>
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
<System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
Public WithEvents FreeMarkers As BindingList(Of FreeMarker)
```

Add two functions to your class:

```vb
Public Function ShouldSerializeFreeMarkers() As Boolean
    Return False
End Function
Public Sub ResetFreeMarkers()
    Series = Nothing
End Sub
```

And lo and behold: No more design time serialization.

Comment: That same thing can happen if you **want** them to serialize and forget some steps, which is what I thought you were running into.  I dont think you need `ShouldXXX` and `ResetXXX` with `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden` which really means ignore.

Comment: I tried every combination with the designerserialization attribute, but it didn't do very much. Even with hidden the serialization was performed. I don't get it. But at least it works with the functions, even though it's not pretty.